# Call server side request in NextJS middleware

Tags: docker, networking, next.js, port, middleware

I have some middleware in my NextJS server.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/api/:path*"],
};

export function middleware(request) {
  const server = process.env.SERVER_HOST;
  const url = `${server}${request.nextUrl.pathname.replace("/api", "")}${request.nextUrl.search}`
  return NextResponse.rewrite(
    url,
    { request }
  )
};
```

It takes API routes and redirects them to my backend using the `SERVER_HOST` environment variable. What I want to do though is make the requests server side.

I am running the NextJS frontend with my backend in a Docker container, if the request was server side, I could return the response without having open access to my backend API. The port for my backend could be closed except for inside my Docker container. Instead of exposing the URL of backend, I can just have the `SERVER_HOST` variable use Docker configurations. Basically I want to use `http://backend:8000` instead of `http://example.com:8000` for `SERVER_HOST`.

Comment: You can use server components, make the call from your `Next.js` to your server, and the client will use the response from that. https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#thinking-in-server-components

Comment: If this is fine, I can write an answer showing you how to do this.

Comment: @RobinThomas Server components would require restructuring all requests in my codebase though no? I am wondering how to make the server side request directly in the `middleware.js` file.

Comment: What if you do the data fetching from server, and pass the result to the client during rendering time. So your Next.js client don't have to make a `fetch` call to the middleware. Will that work?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but wouldn't that mean I would have to have all requests made beforehand? The requests I'm making are page and user specific and must be made clientside.

Comment: If all your requests from client-side need to get response from a backend service without exposing the url of backend side, you can either: 1) use a proxy. this is what you are doing with middleware currently. 2) use server side rendering to get the data and pass it to clientside before the rendering starts on clientside